# Injecting components into a POJO using OSGi

Tags: java, osgi

I'm new to OSGi and I'm interested in retrofitting some of my jars as OSGi bundles.
However I do not want to introduce additional dependencies to any osgi-specific libraries.

As such annotations are out of the question as are programmatic calls to bundle contexts and what not.

I have found a near match to my requirements in declarative services which allows me to expose my lower level bundles without impacting dependencies however at the higher level (where i actually need to consume the services) i'm still a bit stuck.

I understand that the component xml can be used to declare implementations of services (which i already use for my lower level jars) but also to inject service instances into a specific POJO.

Now my question: how do I get access to the osgi-managed POJO which has the services injected into it? Is it at all possible without introducing new dependencies or do I have to do it programmatically?

If the latter is the case can someone point me in the direction of some code to do it, in other words the component-equivalent of bundleContext.getServiceReference()?

**UPDATE**

To clarify, if you take the fifth part of this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGiServices/article.html

He declares a component.xml file which uses reference binding to inject a service into the object QuoteConsumer.
Great, now how do I get an instance of QuoteConsumer that has the necessary services injected into it, I can't very well do "new QuoteConsumer()" right?

**UPDATE2**

Currently I am registering the instance created by osgi as a static variable which can be requested, I'm thinking this is not the best method especially because I can't set the constructor to private. (the latter would at least result in a true singleton)

Basically the Factory class has:

```
private void activate() {
    instance = this;
}
```

**UPDATE3**

A full example of a factory:

```
public class Factory {

    private static Factory instance;

    public static Factory getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Factory();
        return instance;
    }

    private MyInterface implementation;

    public void setMyInterface(MyInterface implementation) {
        this.implementation = implementation;
    }

    public void unsetMyInterface(MyInterface implementation) {
        implementation = null;
    }

    public MyInterface getMyInterface() {
        if (implementation == null) {
            ServiceLoader<MyInterface> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(MyInterface.class);
            Iterator<MyInterface> iterator = serviceLoader.iterator();
            if (iterator.hasNext())
                implementation = iterator.next();
            else
                implementation = new MyInterfaceStub();
        }
        return implementation;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void activate() {
        instance = this;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void deactivate() {
        instance = null;
    }
}
```

Any client code can then do:

```
Factory.getInstance().getMyInterface();
```

and receive the OSGi loaded service, the SPI loaded one or a stub.
You can still manually set the service instance if necessary.

**UPDATE4**

To clarify further: this pattern is not meant for applications that are designed from the ground up to be run in an OSGi container but rather for low level libraries that have to run everywhere and even when on an OSGi container must not assume that all consumers are actually using OSGi.

Answer (score 2):

You sound confused ... :-) A service is a replacement for static factories so your factory should not have to exist.

The whole idea of DS is that for each component:

1. wait until its dependencies are met
2. create an instance
3. bind the instance to its dependencies
4. call activate on the instance
5. register the instance as a service

So whenever you get a service managed by DS it already is injected (bound) with its dependencies. So as long as you stay with service dependencies you never need static factories ... The whole idea of service is that you do NOT have static factories and can only work with (injected) instances. One of the best parts of OSGi is that you rarely work with factories.

One remark about the requirement not to use annotations. The OSGi annotations are class time only, they do not create a runtime dependency. I strongly suggest to use them since they make services as lightweight as a class and are typesafe in contrast to XML.

One trick to use the annotations and not clutter your code is to create extend your implementation classes that you want to be an OSGi component and add the annotations on this class.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The reason behind the factory implementation is that the module should run in any environment. So in general all my modules "expect" managed injection but should fall back to the factory pattern if that didn't happen. But it is perhaps a bit silly to have the factory support OSGi then, it could just use SPI :)

Comment: Unless you are retrofitting an existing factory used by modules that are not OSGi-enabled?

Comment: Well, in an OSGi world things seem pretty simple and straightforward: every object is a component. So in the non-OSGi world you need some DI engine to do the injection.

Answer (score 1):

To access a service, you declare a reference to it from another component:

```
@Reference
public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

You might find the [Bndtools tutorial](http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html) will help to clarify the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you are on the right track. You can use a static field if it is convenient.

The important thing is that you make the rest of your code deal with the QuoteConsumer appearing and disappearing. So, put in your activator the code to do what you need to do when the QuoteConsumer is available (register it in some field, call some initialization code, I don't know) and put in your deactivate the code you need to indicate that the QuoteConsumer is no longer available.

Comment: The code currently basically allows for three modes of operation: OSGi, SPI and manual setting without introducing new dependencies. So if the OSGi instance is removed (or never present to begin with) it will fall back to SPI and if that doesn't work you are responsible for managing it yourself. I will update the original question with example code