# Does a DTO/POJO rise to the qualification of a configurable service in OSGi/DS?

Tags: kotlin, osgi

*Note: This is the first question in a series of question I'll have, all relating to the same environment.*

Currently, I'm using the ConfigurationAdmin service as a configuration persistence mechanism, dumb data holder, and convenient cross-bundle updater. This feels wrong, so I'm trying to make it more right.

I'm writing a game in which everything should be configurable at runtime. This lead me down the ConfigurationAdmin route for wiring things together.

The game by its nature doesn't do anything, and instead, functionality is provided by the combination of bundles available.

One bundle introduces the concept of Species. To maintain as high a degree of flexibility as possible, a Species is really just a name.

```
@Component(...)
@Designate(...)
class Species {

    lateinit var name: String

    @Activate
    fun activate(config: SpeciesConfig) {
        name = config.name
    }
}
```

All additional functionality relating to a Species must be provided by a separate bundle. For example, another bundle introduces the concept of a Pokemon. A Pokemon is just a member of a Species, just like humans are a member of the Homo Sapiens Sapiens species.

```
@Component(...)
class Pokemon {

    @Reference
    lateinit var species: Species
}
```

I've been using Declarative Services (DS) to automatically set the `species` reference.

Here though, you can see that neither `Species` nor `Pokemon` are really services, rather `Species` is a name and persistent identity, and `Pokemon` is a persistent identity, and reference to a `Species`. The only methods that might be implemented for these classes are the usual `hashCode`, `toString` and `equals`.

This realization is what first tipped me off that perhaps ConfigurationAdmin is not the right tool; that perhaps a `SpeciesRepository` or `PokemonRepository` might be better suited for the job of storing the configuration.

**Question:** Do DTO/POJOs like Species rise to the qualification of a service, defined by OSGi/DS, given that there could range from dozens to thousands of Species defined, with none, one, many, or all of them available during runtime?

EDIT: I noticed that Peter Kriens said in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855938/injecting-components-into-a-pojo-using-osgi?rq=1#comment24357429_16871533)

> Well, in an OSGi world things seem pretty simple and straightforward: every object is a component. So in the non-OSGi world you need some DI engine to do the injection.

Maybe it is okay to have things this small be components?

Comment: Are you sure they really are POJOs? The way you say, sounds more like DTOs.

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski They are more like DTOs than POJOs. However, they're not exactly the type of DTO in the core spec.